# MySQL using cursor loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL table which contains 3 columns, the columns are named the following: `TypeID`, `PropertyID`, `ValueID`.

Let's say the table has the following rows:

```
| TypeID | PropertyID | ValueID |
| 45     | 266        | 736     |
| 46     | 266        | 736     |
| 50     | 266        | 736     |
| 52     | 266        | 736     |
| 50     | 229        | 628     |
| 52     | 229        | 628     |
```

I'm looking to select the TypeID when ValueID matches both 736 and 628 which is the case for both 50 and 52.

Please let me know if this needs explaining further.

Comment: Group by on `TypeID`, provide `ValueId` as IN clause and find distinct count of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `GROUP BY` :

```
select TypeID
from table t
where ValueID in (736, 628)
group by TypeID
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you have duplicate `ValueID` then you need `COUNT(DISTINCT ValueID)`.

If you want to all columns then you can do `JOIN` :

```
select t.*
from table t inner join
     (select TypeID
      from table t
      where ValueID in (736, 628)
      group by TypeID
      having count(*) = 2
     ) tt 
    on tt.TypeID = t.TypeID;
```

Comment: If I wanted to create a new table in MySQL with 3 columns (same as the previous table) to store the results in. How would I go about select TypeID, PropertyID, ValueID as I only want to group by TypeID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to fetch the records

```
select TypeID from table where ValueID=736 or ValueID=628
    group by TypeID
    having count(distinct ValueID) > 1;
```